# How to align TableForm entries at the decimal point and give it two-digit right-side floating point precision for monetary amounts?

Tags: style, printing, output-formatting

My question essentially asks everything but I shall rephrase it to make certain it is well understood.

**1.** How to print all entries in rows of a column so that they align perfectly at the decimal point.

**2.** How to make 2-digit floating point precision for cents values (i.e. $1.98)?

**3.** If this cannot be done with TableForm can you suggest another option?

Here is my Mathematica code...

```
carValue := 
 RecurrenceTable[{a[i] == a[i - 1] * 0.90, a[1] == 30000 , 
   y[i] == i}, {y, a}, {i, 15}]
TableForm[carValue , TableHeadings -> {None, {"Year", "Car Price"}}]
Labeled[Select[carValue, #[[2]] < 8000 &, 1][[1, 
  1]], "Year when valued less than $8000:", Left]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
carValue := 
 RecurrenceTable[{
    a[i] == a[i - 1]*0.7
    , a[1] == 30000
    , y[i] == i}
    , {y,a}, {i, 15}]

Grid[
    Join[
       {{"Year", Item["Car Price", Alignment -> Right]}}
      ,Round[carValue, 0.01]
      ]
    , Alignment -> "."
    , Dividers -> {None, {False,True, False}}]
```

[image]

Notes :

`TableForm` has probably no way to align on the decimal point.

With `Tableform`, a workaround could be to use `NumberForm[#, {10,2}] &` to have equally formatted numbers, but it gives :

[image]

I don't like the 00 after the decimal point. 
  Furthermore it' s not in the philosophy of your question.

That's the reason why I have used Grid.

But Grid doesnt' have the option `TableHeading`

This is not a problem, 
  it suffices to add a row with the information. 
    (Grid is very robust. It accepts rows of different length, 
    which is very usefull)

`Round` is used to have only to 2 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: thank you so much. your grid solution works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be

```
carValue = RecurrenceTable[{a[i] == a[i - 1]*0.90, a[1] == 30000, y[i] == i}, {y, a}, {i, 15}];

carValueFixed = {First[#], 
     PaddedForm[Last[#], {7, 2}, DigitBlock -> 3, 
      NumberSeparator -> ",", NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}]} & /@ carValue;

TableForm[carValueFixed, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Year", "Car Price"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you. another fine solution.